# Change iOS Status Bar Color on different views

Tags: ios, cordova

Im building an iOS app using PhoneGap. My initial view is a login screen. On this screen I would like the status bar to be white. But once you login and go to the actual app, id like the status bar text to be black since my navigation bar is white. Is there anyway to tell the app to change the status bar text color from one page to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present there is no way to do this using the phonegap framework however version 3.1 is being release immanently (within a week) and I can only assume that this feature is being at least worked on as this is a core feature of the new IOS7 so keep an eye on the phonegap blog for announcements.

http://phonegap.com/blog/